# Microsoft Native Unit Test for C++ - where is the Logger output going?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019

Trying out C++ unit testing in Visual Studio 2019. Have added a C++ `Native Unit Test Project` unit test project to my solution. Then added the following `Logger` messages:

```
TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE(ClassInitialize)
{
    Logger::WriteMessage("Setup on test class. Where will this appear?");
}

// ...

TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
{
    Logger::WriteMessage("Test method. Where is this message going??");
}
```

The tests are picked up by the Visual Studio `Test Explorer` and run successfully. Breakpoints are also hit if the tests are debugged. According to the [Microsoft documentation on Logger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference?view=vs-2022#logger), output should appear in the Visual Studio `Output Window`, but the messages are not being displayed.

Where is `Logger` sending its' output?

Comment: I'm sure that's where it used to go, I've just tested, and at least in VS2022, The output for TestMethod1 is not going to Output Window but instead is shown in the Test Detail Summary for that given test.

Comment: @user20716902: Ah, found it in VS2019 as you state - on the Test Detail Summary. Wow. Firstly, that's not what the documentation states, and secondly that's less useful than expected as the test has to complete to see the output. Could you knock up your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the MS documentation states "The logger class contains static methods to write to the **Output Window**" this no longer seems to be the case.

The output from the `Logger` Class can now be seen in the **Test Detail Summary**, after the unit tests have been run.

Output from the `Logger::WriteMessage` that is contained in `TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)` will appear in the Test Detail Summary for that given unit test.

Output from the `Logger::WriteMessage` that is contained in `TEST_CLASS_INITIALIZE(ClassInitialize)` will appear in the **first** test method that is executed during that test run.

Comment: Thanks. Am able to confirm this is the answer for VS2019. You also tested in VS2022 as well (thanks!). I have raised the documentation error with Microsoft. They are typically responsive, so hopefully the error will be fixed soon.

Comment: I also raised this with Microsoft, I've closed mine as a duplicate.

Comment: @AlainD As a work around to get output to the actual Output Window you can use: `OutputDebugStringW(L"Test method 1.\n");` Just needs adding `#include "windows.h"` This works when right clicking unit tests and selecting Debug.